# Origine de « paumer » dans le sens de « perdre »

Tags: vocabulaire, étymologie, argot

En français actuel, le sens le plus courant de *paumer* est « perdre ». À l'origine, *paumer* est lier à la *paume* de la main.

Si je vois bien le lien entre une main et d'autres sens désuets de *paumer* comme « frapper », « être frappé », « attraper », le lien avec « perdre » m'échappe.

Sur le Wiktionnaire, [Urhixidur](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/Utilisateur%3aUrhixidur) a [contribué](http://fr.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=paumer&diff=prev&oldid=1172488) l'explication suivante :

> À l’époque moderne, le sens de « prendre » s’est inversé et a donné « perdre », « égarer », pour ensuite acquérir une version pronominale.

Mais je ne vois pas d'où pourrait surgir une telle inversion de sens.

Le [*Trésor de la langue française*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/paumer) renvoie pour le sens « perdre » aux [*Ballades en jargon*](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ballades_en_jargon) de François Villon. Je n'ai pas trouvé le passage concerné.

Le TLF renvoie également pour *se paumer* « s'égarer » à [Lorédan Larchey, *Supplément aux neuvième et dixième éditions du "Dictionnaire d'argot"* (1883), p. 116](http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k203046v/f142.image.r=.langEN), qui ne donne que le sens. Quant au [*Dictionnaire de l'Académie française*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie9/paumer) indique que le sens de « perdre » date du XV<sup>e</sup> siècle, sans autre explication.

Alors d'où vient ce sens du mot *paumer* ? S'il y a eu un glissement de « prendre » vers « perdre », comment diable cela s'est-il passé ? Y a-t-il seulement un lien étymologique entre ces deux sens ?

Comment: Pour _Ballades en jargon_, chercher « _paulme_ » [ici](http://www.poesies.net/villonballadeenjargon.txt), 2x. Merci.

Answer (score 8):

Il existe une hypothèse, relatée dans le [Supplément aux 7e et 8e éditions du Dictionnaire historique d'argot, contenant 2784 mentions nouvelles](http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k6471590j), comme quoi il s'agirait à l'origine de 2 mots différents qui ont évolués vers la même orthographe (j'imagine que ce phénomène doit avoir un nom scientifique) :

[À la page XI](http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k6471590j/f19.image.r=paumer.langFR) :

> De même pour paumoier (saisir) et paumer (tomber en défaillance), d'où
>   viennent paumer (prendre) et paumer : perdre (7 bis) 7 bis. Ce double
>   sens de paumer, en apparence si contradictoire, s'explique mieux si on
>   considère le premier paumer comme une forme de notre empaumer, tandis
>   que le second vient de pausmer qui voulait dire autrefois : se pâmer,
>   défaillir.

Il existe aussi des indications comme quoi un sens ancien de paumer serait giffler ; il se pourrait que cette acceptation négative aie apporté notre sens actuel, à vérifier.

Ainsi, dans [Le langage parisien au XIXe siècle : facteurs sociaux, contingents linguistiques, faits sémantiques, influences littéraires](http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k5433966k) :

> Paumer. ce mot est bas et du petit peuple de Paris. Il veut dire
>   souffleter.

Enfin, [L'argot ancien... : 1455-1850](http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k405680s), considère que la différence de sens vient d'un phénomène d'antiphrase. Ainsi, [p. 129](http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k405680s/f141.image.r=paumer.langFR) :

> PAUMER, qui signifie en même temps prendre... et perdre, ce dernier
>   sens par antiphrase.

Faites votre marché dans tout ça.

Answer (score 3):

On lit ceci dans le Littré à la définition de paume qui apparaît comme un jeu sur lequel on prend des paris :

> *« (Absolument) La paume, le jeu de la paume. J'ai perdu de l'argent à la paume. »*

Par ailleurs, en lutte ou en catch, le lutteur peut signifier son abandon en tapant le sol plusieurs fois avec la paume de la main. Il a paumé, il a donc perdu.

Answer (score 0):

« Tripot » : c’était le nom qu’on donnait au XVIe à une salle de jeu de paume. Or, très vite, ces salles se sont transformées en lieux de paris, plus ou moins clandestins. D’où notre « tripot ».
On pouvait donc *"paumer"* pas mal au tripot du jeu de paume.